# How to set text area display text based on Cookie value on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, plsql

I have a text area in the middle of my page like so:

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="carowner_notes" ROWS=6 COLS=25 ALIGN="center" value="decodeURIComponent('test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest')" onkeydown="check_length(50)" onkeyup="check_length(50)">
decodeURIComponent(test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest)
</TEXTAREA>
```

I am trying to set the display contents of the box to be the decoded string as the page loads. Is there an easy way to do this?

Right now my box looks like this:

[image]

I need it to look like this:

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

HTML:

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="carowner_notes" ROWS=6 COLS=25 ALIGN="center" value="decodeURIComponent('test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest')" onkeydown="check_length(50)" onkeyup="check_length(50)">
</TEXTAREA>
<SCRIPT>$("#carowner_notes").ready(function(){
                                document.getElementsByName('carowner_notes')[0].value = decodeURIComponent('test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest');
                                });
</SCRIPT>
```

I am using PL/SQL so this shows passing in the variable:

```
v_notes_cookieval varchar2 := 'test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest';
htp.formTextareaOpen('carowner_notes','6', '25', 'center',     'value="decodeURIComponent('''||v_notes_cookieval||''')" onkeydown="check_length(50)" onkeyup="check_length(50)"');
htp.formTextareaClose;
htp.script('$("#carowner_notes").ready(function(){
                                document.getElementsByName(''carowner_notes'')[0].value = decodeURIComponent('''||v_notes_cookieval||''');
                                });');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this code on page load.

```
var textarea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea')[0]

textarea.value = decodeURIComponent('test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest')
```

Obviously, you'll probably want to assign an `ID` to the `TEXTAREA` node in the event that you have more than one `TEXTAREA` node.

Also, the `'test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest'` doesn't have to be hardcoded. You can pull that from the query/hash of the URL, or elsewhere.

Comment: I ended up using jQuery and doing the following: `$("#carowner_notes").ready(function(){
                                    document.getElementsByName('carowner_notes')[0].value = decodeURIComponent('test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest');
                                    });` so basically the same idea as your answer only I did it upon loading the textarea element rather than the entire document. I also am passing in the value rather than hard coding it.

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad you came to a solution that works for you.